# In Microsoft Teams, where can I see my upcoming scheduled calls?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I got an email saying that an appointment was scheduled in Microsoft Teams; however even if I click "accept" I can't find the call anywhere inside Teams; the only way I can access it is through the link in the email (which deletes itself when I click "accept" so I have to undelete it in order to access the call!) - am I missing something obvious or is this feature just not available?

Answer (score 0):

I presume what you called "schedule calls" are actually scheduled meetings. If that is the case, you will find them by going to your calendar in Microsoft Teams.

[image: IMG:]

Comment: Hmm, I went to the calendar and I don't see any of my previous meetings...

Comment: @ekolis Do you see your upcoming meetings?